# Converting any token to wei in solidity

Tags: solidity, ether

How to convert any token like USDC, BNB  to WEI in solidity? Is there any mathematical formula for this?

Comment: Use my [`ERC20Normalizer`](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-contracts/blob/cc74c4eda1e02c9d36ebb7c00230ee8c97e4be97/src/token/erc20/ERC20Normalizer.sol) contract.